# URL rewrite for / causing 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewite rule that should redirect the index page (/) to a different page so I can deal with all of my content in there. However adding this second rule caused a 500 internal server error and I am not sure why.

This is in my .htaccess file

Its the 3rd line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ search.php?postcode=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /turnstile.php?goto=home [L]
```

Comment: You are creating an infinite rewrite loop. Also everything goes to the last rule, even if the first one matches (the last one gets applied anyway)

Comment: I had a feeling thats what was going on but how can I fix that

Comment: You need to make sure that your last rule does not match its result. And consider using `RewriteCond`

Comment: not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude the destination you are rewriting to.

```
RewriteRule ^((?!turnstile.php).*)$ /turnstile.php?goto=home [L]
```